# add package in android that has been publish in playstore

Tags: java, android, production, android-package-managers

Currently, my package in androidis `id.b3n.hysteria`

I added some scripts for ecommerce but because of an update from the client, I want to update my package, for example:

- id.b3n.hysteria.ecommerce
- id.b3n.hysteria.booking
- id.b3n.hysteria.game

Is it a problem if I upload to play store such an update? It will be a big problem if the apps must reset from 0 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store. If you want to upload a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you sign it with) must be the same as the original APK—if you change the application ID, Google Play Store treats the APK as a completely different app. So once you publish your app, you should never change the application ID. However you can create different variant.

Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

Comment: akh... ok2 so if i not change the
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.b3n.hysteria" >
and 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    //buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id.b3n.hysteria"

it's no problem right?

Comment: @Benikurniawan   You have to keep your package id "id.b3n.hysteria" if app is already in the playstore.  if you change this app will be treated as a new app in the play store.  so in brief if app is in play store you can not change the package otherwise it will be treated as new app.

Comment: well i got handover project and i see to much file at id.b3n.hysteria.. it has more than 20 java file.. i can make it more viewable if i add anothe sub package.. and my company want add feature like booking etc.. if i let this file this much.. it's gonna hurt my eyes balls.. hahah thats why i want keep it that package identifire and add some sub package